# Админка и Фронт часть на laravel

Tags: laravel

В данный момент изучаю Laravel, используя 5.8 версию, после Yii2. Со старта столкнулся с проблемой разделения приложения на части, в Yii2 advanced уже реализован данный вопрос, потому я немного озадачен.

Порылся в интернете, но внятный ответ так и не нашел.

Уже думаю использовать 2 приложения с одной базой данных, но не знаю тонкости и подводные камни, которые возникнут в дальнейшем.

Подскажите, как это сделать правильно. В дальнейшем приложение должно постоянно расширятся.

Comment: Не понятно, Вы хотите два приложения развернуть в рамках одного ларавела, и тогда по сути они будут разграничены только роутами, или это будет два независимых приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду, но в laravel в роутах имеется route::group() который может помочь сгруппировать запросы, а если хотите писать админскую часть на laravel, то можете использовать october cms, она сделана на основе laravel